# iCloud with Core Data, Data Persistency When iCloud is Off

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I would like to add iCloud to my Core Data app. The only thing I want out of iCloud is the persistence of data through deletion and re-installation of the App. I do not need multiple device support for the app at the moment. I have managed the iCloud work with Core Data. However, there is one scenario that I am not sure how to handle. Right now, if the iCloud is on for the app, the data that is saved in the iCloud persists through deletion and re-installation of the app which is what I want. But when the user turns off the iCloud for the app, the data that was saved in the iCloud does not show anymore which I think is normal and when user creates new data, the new data is saved in the local storage of the app. So it looks like that I have two separate storages, one iCloud and one local. So my question is, when the iCloud is off and data values are created and saved into the local storage of the app, how to make sure those data values get added to the data values that were saved in the iCloud, when the iCloud is turned back on?

Here is the relevant section of my App Delegate:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) 
    {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) 
    {
        return nil;
    }
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    return _managedObjectContext;
}


- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel 
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) 
    {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    NSURL *documentsDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    NSURL *storeURL = [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Model.sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *failureReason = @"There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.";

    NSDictionary *storeOptions =
    @{NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey: @"MyAppCloudStore"};

    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:storeOptions error:&error]) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = @"Failed to initialize the application's saved data";
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason;
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error;
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:9999 userInfo:dict];

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```